# Silent push notification using davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Tags: ios, laravel, notifications, apple-push-notifications, silentpush

I'm trying to send silent push notification to iOS using [davibennun/laravel-push-notification](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification). I just want to know where to add `'content-available' => 1`.
Here is my code:

```
$notification = PushNotification::Message(
            'Message.',
            array(
            'content-available' => 1,
                'custom' => array('custom data' => array(
                    'customKey'=> 'customValue',
                    'abc' => '',
            ))
        ));
```

Comment: what do you mean by silent push notification?

Comment: A silent push notification is a hidden instruction that is delivered to the app on a user's device. Instead of causing an interaction with the user like a typical push notification, silent notifications will simply quietly deliver a certain set of data to the app, allowing the app to act upon that data.
Source: [link]https://help.localytics.com/t/what-is-a-silent-push-notification/39